# Why does 'event' appear as a keyword in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, keyword

I am trying to build a small T-SQL database. And being a good programmer, I obviously looked up all reserved keywords to avoid using these as names ([I found a list from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql)). The word **"event"** is not in the list, so I decided to use that (not *just* because it wasn't in the list of course).

However, when I write it in SQL Server Management Studio, the name is highlighted with blue, as you can see below. Why is that, if it is not a reserved keyword?

[image: 'Event' appears to be a keyword]

Comment: There are *keywords* and there are *reserved keywords*. Have a look at MySQL: The keywords marked with a `R` are reserved: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: @juergend, The OP asked about SQL-Server, and your comment is for MySQL, maybe it is the same info in both, just consider this comment as note.

Comment: @juergend thanks. I will try to avoid it then, as I suppose this is best practice(?). I still cannot find a list for T-SQL (or generic SQL), but I guess it's pretty similar.

Comment: Yes, it is generally best practice to avoid giving your objects names that are keywords (reserved or not). For example, you could quite easily make a table like this: `CREATE TABLE Value (GUID decimal(10,0), date varchar(10), time int);` I'd strongly recommend against it though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a special keyword for SQL server. As you can see;

[CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-event-notification-transact-sql)

[CREATE EVENT SESSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-event-session-transact-sql)

So, I suggest you to don't use this kind of keywords to don't get confusion.

Also, still if you want to stay with this keyword, you can provide the query with `[]` like `omr.[event]`

Comment: Thank you. No, I do not want to use it. I despise people who uses keywords for names, without even bother checking their use. I changed it to a different name :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using Events or SQL Server Extended Event data, database programmers can handle events with the help of [DDL triggers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.105).aspx) . For example, you can log when a table is dropped, here is the [DDL trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/log-drop-table-in-sqlserver-database-using-ddl-trigger.aspx) codes for this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name 
ON { ALL SERVER | DATABASE } 
[ WITH <ddl_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]
{ FOR | AFTER } {*event_type | event_group } [ ,...n ]
AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] | EXTERNAL NAME < method specifier >  [ ; ] }
```